# How to: Add Chapters, Sections, markers to video files to help direct access, skipping/ fast forwarding?

Tags: video-editor, editing, file-formats, formats

How to: Add Chapters, Sections, markers to video files to help direct access, skipping/ fast forwarding?

PS: Asking for Non ISO video file formats that support these: MKV does for sure, I am wondering about other most popular video file formats such as:

- MPG
- MP4
- AVI
- M4V
- MKV
- FLV
- MOV/ QT

https://superuser.com/questions/240981/how-to-add-chapters-or-bookmarks-to-movies
The above similar question was for Mac only, and this one is asking for bit more.

- What video file formats support such markers
- How can a person easily add such markers to existing video files?

PS: Prefer a free/ non-commercial way of doing so on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

MP4 format does support chapters. You can use free [Drax](https://drax.codeplex.com/) utility to create them. Please note that not all video players support MP4 chapters. You need to find one that does ([VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.html) ?)

Comment: What about MPG, AVI files? Can they support (when playing via VLC?)

Comment: VLC does not save the bookmarks for future viewing of the mp4.